# JSON.NET not converting all of a sudden

Tags: c#, rest, json.net, restsharp

I was writing some code to collect data from an API using RestSharp and JSON.net libraries. This was working great until recently when my models started coming back null (with no changes to my knowledge). The content of the query has information so this should not be a null object. Result is showing up as null.

Below is a snippet example of how I am doing the conversion:

```
 IRestResponse summaryResponse = summaryClient.Execute(summaryRequest);
        RootobjectSummary result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootobjectSummary>(summaryResponse.Content);
        return result;
```

Below is the model used above:

```
    public class RootobjectSummary
{
    public InsuranceSummary InsuranceSummary { get; set; }
}

public class InsuranceSummary
{
    public int InsuredTenantsCount { get; set; }
    public int NewPoliciesCount { get; set; }
    public int CancelledPoliciesCount { get; set; }
    public float PercentageOfTenantsInsured { get; set; }
    public float CoverageTotal { get; set; }
    public float PaymentTotal { get; set; }
    public float RefundTotal { get; set; }
    public float NetPaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, this is the JSON response I get that should be converted:

```
"{\"insurance_summary\":{\"insured_tenants_count\":7,\"new_policies_count\":7,\"cancelled_policies_count\":0,\"percentage_of_tenants_insured\":13.20754716981132,\"coverage_total\":130000.0,\"payment_total\":0.0,\"refund_total\":0.0,\"net_payment_amount\":0.0,\"start_date\":\"2018-07-03\",\"end_date\":\"2018-07-03\",\"facility_policy_number\":\"ABC12345\",\"master_policy_number\":\"CBA54321\"},\"meta\":{\"status_code\":200,\"status_message\":\"OK\",\"status_cat\":\"https://http.cat/200\",\"request_method\":\"GET\",\"request_id\":\"5a598888-eab3-4fab-9474-8856418f506b\",\"parameters\":{\"CreatedAfter\":\"2017-01-01-01T00:00:00-07:00\",\"CreatedBefore\":\"2018-07-01T00:00:00-07:00\",\"oauth_consumer_key\":\"GVelfUpJTn2NqGNf1bwJTbVTl5MDdHp3uTXyDaCd\",\"oauth_nonce\":\"9072365\",\"oauth_signature_method\":\"PLAINTEXT\",\"oauth_timestamp\":\"1530632568\",\"oauth_version\":\"1.0\",\"oauth_signature\":\"TRDNYFta6z8zNwE5lFCErnShnYLEvsFebz0wPRdy\\u0026\",\"facility_id\":\"b2af724f-3af4-4d62-94e4-88211763d18e\"}}}"
```

Comment: Does JSON.net convert between the likes of `insured_tenants_count` and `InsuredTenantsCount` automatically by default, or does it need to have an additional option specified?  Perhaps you've removed that option unintentionally at some point?

Comment: @JamesThorpe you know, I wasn't sure of that myself a few months ago, I  don't recall changing the model from what the json sends but it may have been automatically done by resharper. I will need to go check that out, I didn't even think of that.

Comment: Resharper will absolutely suggest changing underscored names to camel cased ones, if you chose "fix naming in file/project/solution" it would have done them all everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure deserializer to work with snake case naming:

```
DefaultContractResolver contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
    NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
};
RootobjectSummary result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootobjectSummary>(summaryResponse.Content, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = contractResolver
});
```

Comment: Awesome, This ties into what James Thorpe said in a comment. I didn't realize my naming was changed by resharper when cleaning up the code. I will need to try this and I will let you know!